# HTTPURLConnection.getInputStream() Takes a very long time?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm uploading an image file using a HttpURLConnection which takes about 3 seconds for a 5MB file with all the headers, but the moment I open an InputStream with .getInputStream(), the method takes about 8+ seconds to return a stream with. Which is an issue because it seems the upload progress bar gives a bad UX if I have multiple images to upload, they have a considerable pause between each upload, so the progress bar just stops for a couple of seconds between uploads. I've done some googling but no one else seems to have an issue with it?

Normally I would assume the server is slow, but seeing as uploading only takes a couple of seconds, downloading the word 'success' or 'fail' shouldn't really be that much of an issue!

Heres some code! Am I setting anything up wrong initially? 
*Note: This is also within an AsyncTask*

```
    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dObject.Data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    String Tag="3rd";
    try
    {
        //------------------ CLIENT RE QUEST        
        Log.e(Tag,"Inside second Method");      

        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL    
        URL url = new URL(_urlString);
        //connectURL is a URL object
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + _fileLocation +"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + _fileLocation +"\"" + lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

        // create a buffer of maximum size
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];



        // read file and write it into form...  
        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //int value = (int)(((float)((float)totalRead / (float) fileSize)) * 100);

            totalRead += bytesRead;
            //Publish the progress out to be displayed
            publishProgress(totalRead);



            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


        // close streams
        Log.e(Tag,"File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();

        Log.e("TIME", "PRE GETINPUTSTREAM");
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
        Log.e("TIME", "POST GETINPUTSTREAM");
        //  retrieve the response from server
        int ch;


        //Build the respose and log
        StringBuilder b =new StringBuilder();
        while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
            b.append( (char)ch );
        }
        String s=b.toString();      
        Log.i("Response",s);
        dos.close();

        return;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.get().e("3");
    }

    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ErrorHandler.get().e("2");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Normally I would assume the server is slow, but seeing as uploading only takes a couple of seconds, downloading the word 'success' or 'fail' shouldn't really be that much of an issue!

I suspect that it really is that the server is slow or overloaded.

- The server could be queueing the HTTP requests and only processing a small number at a time in parallel.
- Or it could have a bottleneck in some database activity that is performed before the response containing the file is written to the response.
- Or it could be generating the file on the fly into an in-memory buffer (slow) and then streaming (fast) from the buffer to the HTTP response.
- Or other explanations like this ...

(It is also theoretically possible that there is something funny going on that slows up the delivery of the request to the server.  I would think this was unlikely though.)

---

Have you tried downloading the same file using a web browser?   Do you get the same behaviour there?

Comment: Indeed it's the server being slow actually.. I've had to fudge it with saying "Uploading' while uploading, and then showing an indeterminate progress bar with "Finalizing" while waiting for the server to respond! I think my company should upgrade hosting!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that getInputStream looks slow because this method initialize the ssl handshake (on  a https URL call). After the first call, others calls are OK